# How do you model arms you want to animate?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

So I've got a model and I want to animate its arms. This is my rough first attempt at creating the arm's basic shapes: [image]

Each object is mirrored. I'm only mentioning that in case it's important.

What I would like to know is
a). Whether or not having all these mirrored, separated objects will be compatible for animation
And b). I've seen some tutorials where the sculptor was somehow able to join each object together and somehow mold the forearm around the sphere acting as the elbow to make it look more smooth and cover up the sphere, but they don't go into much detail on how they're able to accomplish that. How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not near my pc right now but you should have a look into creating a simple rig, this video shows how to do this

https://youtu.be/SBYb1YmaOMY